# Populating dropdown list with two columns from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html-select

I'm working on MVC3 project.

At my controller I already have a code that gets the `Descr` column from `StockClass` table. After that I fill a ViewBag with this list in order to retrieve it from the view and populate the dropdown list.

Currently is working fine but only shows `Descr` field (obviously). What i want is populate the dropdown list with two fields (`Code` and `Descr`) in this format: "code - descr".

I tried several ways but i cannot find the way to code the @Html helper correctly.

In my controller...

```
var oc = dba.StockClass.OrderBy(q => q.Code).ToList();
ViewBag.OrderClass = new SelectList(oc, "StockClassId", "Descr");
```

In my view....

```
@Html.DropDownList("StockClassID", (SelectList)ViewBag.OrderClass)
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is an HTML Helper which will do that for you, but you can get what you're after like this:

```
var oc = dba.StockClass
    .OrderBy(q => q.Code)
    .ToDictionary(q => q.StockClassId, q => q.Code + " - " + q.Descr);

ViewBag.OrderClass = new SelectList(oc, "Key", "Value");
```

This also has the advantage of making the uses of `StockClassId`, `Code` and `Descr` refactor-friendly - if you rename those properties you won't be able to compile without updating this bit of code to match.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works like a charm!! And you're right about renaming the properties...Thanks a lot!